# Best way to track user activity using JWT and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, spring-mvc, session, jwt

I am in a bit situation where I need clarification. I have developed a Full-stack web application using Angular 8 for a Front end and web services using Spring boot.

I have implemented authentication and authorisation using JWT token, here everything is working fine, but I am not able to maintain the state i.e. when the user is logged in or logged out.

I am not able to maintain a session, which would be valid when the user is logged in and invalid when the user is logged out.

So if anyone could tell me how to implement session or any other thing by which I could know that which user is logged in or logged out at any particular time.

Comment: You store the JWT client side, if the token is outdated or rejected by the server you log the client out.

Comment: Thank you, but storing JWT token at client side would not tell me when the user is active or inactive.

Comment: Your JWT is sent to the back end on each request, so you will know when a client is active.

Comment: I won't recommend to use jwt for session token, you can read why here https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/17/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens . You can use spring session with redis to maintain you session https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html

Comment: When you store the JWT in angular save the time it has arrived. Usually the JWT expires after 15 minutes so any interactions past that time will redirect the user to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Even I am using JWT token for authentication and authorization.
When you call any api you pass this token for authentication, there you check the validity of the user.
But if you want to know which user is currently logged in and what is the expiry time of that user, you can store the profile in the **localstorage**.
Whenever you want any information of the user you can access it through **localstorage**.

The data stored in localstorage is tab specific. So one tab would have its own data in localstorage.

Comment: ok now suppose JWT token has 15min expiry time, any user after the successful login has the token of 15min but what if the user closes the browser or turned off the system just after the login, then in this scenario the user is active because of token but in physically user is inactive. I cannot monitor this state of the user with JWT.

Comment: When you close the browser, localstorage would also get cleared, so that user is not active in that case also.